# Symfony SASS without Yarn / Node.js

Tags: node.js, symfony, sass, yarnpkg

I'm trying to learn Symfony and precompiling with SASS. The documentation of Symfony4 says I should install the SASS precompiler with the "yarn" command.
(https://symfony.com/doc/master/frontend/encore/css-preprocessors.html)
But I use a webhoster where I'm not allowed to install Node.js so I cannot install/use yarn.
Is there another way to install SASS with Symfony?

Comment: https://github.com/leafo/scssphp

Answer (score 1):

You can (and I think that must) install node in your local develop machine, and only upload to your host the CSS files, not your SASS files.

After you install it locally, you can compile it with:

```
./node_modules/.bin/encore dev
```

I hope this is util for you

[Encore documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/frontend/encore/simple-example.html)